# PHP get method always 1?

Tags: php, debugging, web, get

Why is the php get method value always 1? Here's my code.

```
echo isset($_GET['page']);
switch(isset($_GET['page'])){
    case 'a':
        echo '1';
        break;      
    case 'b':
        echo 2'';
        break;  
    case 'c':
        echo '3';
        break;          
    case 'd':
        echo '';
        break;          
    case 'e':
        echo '4';
        break;      
    default:
        echo '5';
}
```

And the value of the get method is always 1, showed in the first line code.
Thanks for answering and helping me out to make a website.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for isset http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isset($_GET['page'])
```

`isset` returns true or false if `$_GET['page']` is set. In this case php treats true as 1.

Use the actual value:

```
echo $_GET['page'];
```

You can check if it's set which is likely what you intended:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    //Do stuff with $_GET['page']
}
```

Comment: thanks man but I must wait 12 minute to accept it :D

Comment: That IS the real answer and I WILL accept it

Comment: Sorry for taking so long time to accept it, but now its accepted @Jim

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
switch(isset($_GET['page'])){
```

should be

```
switch($_GET['page']){
```

as `isset($_GET['page'])` is always true (interpreted as 1) if page is set.

Answer (score 0):

See 1 is printing in the first statement i.e

```
echo isset($_GET['page']);
```

isset() will return 0 or 1, that is why you are getting 1 always!

second thing one mistake in your switch case:

```
switch(isset($_GET['page'])) // wrong because will pass only 0 or 1 in switch case

switch($_GET['page']) // Right will pass the URL page parameter value i.e .php?page=a here a will pass in switch statement
```